# Scrolling bg dont work well on chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome, animation, scroll, background

Everything is working fine, but when I try scrolling fast. Chrome cant handle it (bug few ms to show a bg). On safari is working well, without any problem. I notice that, because of my animation, how can I solved it?

[demo](http://ochutnejvietnam.cz/demo.html)

animation:

```
.cssanimations &.bounce-in {
  visibility: visible;
  @include transform(translateZ(0));
  @include animation($nameOfAnimation $time);
}
```

fixed & scrolling bg:

```
.bg {
  &-fixed {
  position: relative;
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center center;
  background-attachment: fixed;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

in select navigation tab font-weight is bold. due to that visually page little jerks.

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 768px)
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a.selected {
    color: #B17098;
    font-weight:normal;
    opacity: 1;
}
```

if you want font-weight bold in active, than use font-weight bold in normal state as well that problem will resolve. below is code for normal state with bold:

```
.navbar-nav>li>a {
padding-top: 10px;
padding-bottom: 10px;
line-height: 20px;
font-weight: 700;
```